# Ignore the first order with respect to order id with same name

Tags: mysql

I want to query the database:
If two orders in a row are the same then ignore the second one. I used Distinct but I have many orders with the same name with different products so I want to ignore the next order the row with the same name in the row

```
order_id  customer_name  product_name  
234       Jhon           Mango
235       Jhon           Mango
236       Marvel         tomato
237       Paul           Potato
238       Jhon           Banana
```

Comment: Please publish your desired result. And do orders really only have 1 item each?

Comment: You'll need to add another column to handle this case. It can be `created_date`, that will be governed by your application logic.

Comment: And why would repeat orders for the same items and quantities not be legitimate?

Comment: It is just the case user double click on the button order get twice in the database.

Comment: Is there not any query to handle this situation?

Comment: Not really how can code know the difference between a double click error and a repeat order?